# JAVA gettext commons

Tags: java, gettext

I've been trying to get internationalization to work in JAVA (needs to support plurals).  I have a POT file, and from that I've generated a PO file, and I have even managed to compile the JAVA class from it (as per http://xnap-commons.sourceforge.net/gettext-commons/tutorial.html#Creating_Resource_Bundles).

I can however for the life of me not get it to work in my project.  Can anybody perhaps help me get a link to a complete working example project?  All examples that I have found implies that it is a very simple thing to implement, so I'm guessing I'm just being stupid, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Did you follow all steps given at the new homepage of gettext commons? http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/wiki/Tutorial