# Avoid .properties files GNU Gettext java

Tags: java, internationalization, gnu, gettext, po

First, my issue is similar to those two :

[JAVA gettext commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476090/java-gettext-commons)

[error reading .po file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576320/error-reading-po-file-in-java)

- I want to use GNU Gettext utility for internationnalizing my app. I managed to get it working by creating a `translations.properties` file with the proper key-value pair but it wont get my `translations_fr_CA.properties` even if I explicitly set the locale to fr_CA or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH. This was my first issue.
- Second and most important issue : I can't get rid of the .properties file which is crap as I can't use the nice gettext complete msgid . I managed to compile my .po file to a .class with `msgfmt --java2 [...]` but the `ResourceBundle` won't load without a .properties file.

Here is a zip of my current testing project : [java_gettext_testing.zip](http://jeangab.fr.nf/java_gettext_testing.zip)

I included gnu.gettext.GettextResource in the zip to make it simpler. You can compile with `javac test/*.java` and run with `java test.test`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out finally. I don't know why but I cant use .class files without putting them in a package. I reworked my structure and finally I can compile my .po file with

```
msgfmt --java2 -d . -r test.translations translations.po
```

which will compile the ./translations.po file to test/translations.class giving it the appropriate package information.

Now I can do this

```
ResourceBundle myRes = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.translations"); // load my test/translations.class file

GettextResource.gettext(myRes, "message id to translate");
```

Still got to get the locale working but the essential is there for me right now.

**Edit** This question helped me to understand that msgfmt was compiling .po files into "real" java objects [How to use ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464153/how-to-use-resourcebundle)